# How to solve XAML parse errors?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a XAML (Windows 8 WinRT XAML) + C# application that has a XAML UserControl. In the designer, I don't see any issue (no red underlines or similar). The Project also compiles without any errors. 
When I run the application, the application breaks in `InitializeComponent()` with "XAML parse error". I have no idea, how to debug this kind of issue. What would be the steps to identify the problem? Yes, The there is something wrong with the XAML User Control or the ressource dictionary but how would one deal with this kind of error in a structured way?

**[EDIT]**

Ok, it seems that trail-error seems to be the right approach for WinRT.

BTW. I found the issue with **"my"** code.

My project was called "Pegasus.Core" and in the generated `CalenderControl.g.i.cs` file from visual studio, the path was this: `"ms-appx:///Pegasus_Core/View/CalendarControl.xaml"` -> replaced "." with "_"

[The fix url](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739194)

Comment: Are there any warnings or errors in the Output window pane when you run the project?

Comment: My fall back method is to simply start stripping away parts of the XAML (especially if you have a last-working-version) until it works again. At that point, add bits back until it fails. It should give you a good idea of the culprit.

Comment: Take it apart. Remove everything and add things back one bit of code at a time until you find what causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the exception gives you a good hint as to which line it failed on if you watch the exception object. Other than that - removing and re-adding pieces of XAML is what I often end up doing in such cases. It's just a limitation of error reporting in the platform that would be nice if it was improved, but we have to cope with version 1 until the next version hopefully improves things a little bit.

Comment: Thanks. I'd just hoped there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got that . This exception comes when your XAML Markup takes the next line.
To be more specific look into your XAML and check that is there any UI Control definition going into the second line?
Example
    
This shouldn't be the case .move everything in one line